# css two background images

Tags: css

Kind of new to css but I have one image I want on top left corner and then another image I want to repeat after that. Currently I tired:

CSS

```
#topsection{
    background: url('../images/bannerBGs.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background: url('../images/bannerBGl.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    height: 200px; /*Height of top section*/
    color: White;
    text-align:center
}

#topsection a{
    color: #FFFF80;
}

#topsection h1{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 25px;
    text-align:Left
}

#topsection h2{
    margin: 0;
    padding-top: 0px;
    text-align:Center
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>IG Indy Gamers</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/mycss.css" media="screen" />    
</head>
<body>
<div id="maincontainer">

<div id="topsection" > <div class="innertube">
    <h1>IG -Indy Gamers </h1>  
    <FONT style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: blue"><p align='right'><a href="#"> &nbspSignup</a> </font> / <a href='Login.html' id='LoginContent' >Login </a></p> 
    <ul id="list-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Demo's</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Members</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>

</div></div>
```

but the second image just copies over the first. Can you suggest another way to do this. I heard using layers may do it but I know nothing about that yet.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Looks like CSS3 supports [multiple background images](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/); you specify them separated by commas:

```
background: url('banner1.jpg'), url('banner2.jpg');
background-position: left top, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
```

Play with `background-position` until it does what you want.

IE < 9 does not support this feature.

Comment: This Q also helped me with combing gradient with background image http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to create 2 containing elements: 1 for the repeating image. And a 2nd for the image in the top left.

In other words, something along the lines of:

```
<div class="repeatingBgImage">
  <div class="otherBgImage">
    <!-- content -->
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS works in a, well, cascading manner. Anything you declare can and will be overwritten by the next line in the statement, i.e.,

```
.someClass {
  color: yellow;
  color: blue;
}
```

The final color of the text will be blue, not green (yellow+blue=green).

Given your sample...

```
#topsection{
  background: url('../images/bannerBGs.jpg');
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background: url('../images/bannerBGl.jpg');
  background-repeat:repeat-x;
}
```

... the background image will always be `bannerBGl.jpg` and `repeat-x` since it is lower in the declaration of the CSS, thus overwriting the previous bg image and repeat declaration.

Answer (score 1):

If you're targeting new browsers, css3 now can apply two background images on one element. You might want to check this one out

http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/

Answer (score 0):

you css

```
/*TOPSECTION */
#topsection{
background: url('../images/bannerBGs.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background: url('../images/bannerBGl.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
height: 200px; /*Height of top section*/
color: White;
text-align:center
}
```

try this

```
background-image:url('../images/bannerBGs.jpg'),url('../images/bannerBGl.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat-x;
background-position: left top , 20px 30px; 
//background-position  adjust second value which in px until  you meet your requirment
```

Thanks!