# Use CSS gradient over background' image

Tags: html, css, background, background-image, gradient

I've been trying to use a linear gradient on top of my background image, in order to get a fading effect on the bottom of my background, from black to transparent, but can't seem to be able to make it show.

I can only see the gradient or the image but not both of them.

```css
body {
  background: url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat, -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)), to(rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)));
}
```

Answer (score 160, accepted):

Add the url for the background image **at the end of the line**:

```css
.css {
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%),
   url('https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-icon.png?v=c78bd457575a') no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="css"></div>
```

Answer (score 13):

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: url('img/background.jpg') repeat;
}

body:before {
    content: " ";
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(top center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,255,255,0.2) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.5) 100%);
}
```

Note: this is using only webkit, so it will only work in webkit browsers.

Try:

```
-moz-linear-gradient = (Firefox)
-ms-linear-gradient = (IE)
-o-linear-gradient = (Opera)
-webkit-linear-gradient = (Chrome & safari)
```

Answer (score 5):

```css
#multiple-background{
 box-sizing: border-box;
 width: 123px;
 height: 30px;
 font-size: 12pt;
 border-radius: 7px;  
 background: url("https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/woocons1/Checkbox%20Full.png"), linear-gradient(to bottom, #4ac425, #4ac425);
 background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;
 background-position: 5px center, 0px 0px;
    background-size: 18px 18px, 100% 100%;
 color: white; 
 border: 1px solid #e4f6df;
 box-shadow: .25px .25px .5px .5px black;
 padding: 3px 10px 0px 5px;
 text-align: right;
 }
```

```html
<div id="multiple-background"> Completed </div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's how to to it with compass (SCSS/SASS):

```scss
body{
  $colorStart: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  $colorEnd: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
  @include background-image(linear-gradient(to bottom, $colorStart, $colorEnd), url("bg.jpg"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot update the background property and you cannot consider an extra element or pseudo element, you can use `border-image`

Related: https://css-tip.com/gradient-overlay-border-image/

```css
.css {
  height: 250px;
  background: url(https://picsum.photos/id/28/900/600) center/cover; 
}

.css {
  border-image: fill 0
    linear-gradient(#0003,#000); /* your gradient here */ 
}
```

```html
<div class="css"></div>
```