# Can I apply multiple backgrounds at the same time?

Tags: html, css

I've got the following background properties I want to apply to an element:

```
background: url('../img/bg.png') !important;

background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))) !important;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
```

I want the image to be displayed first, and the gradient over it. Is it possible to do this?

Comment: overlay a div over another div. One background per each. CSS3 allows u to do multiple backgrounds per one element however I do not think that applies to doing linear gradient + images

Comment: Read these: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504071/is-it-possible-to-combine-a-background-image-and-css3-gradients, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image

Comment: You can use background: url('img1.png'), url('img2.png'); but i'm not sure if you can do it with a css gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because [gradients are considered images](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-images/#gradients) for the purposes of `background` (or pretty much any CSS property that takes an image), you can simply list the image after the gradient with a comma. The caveat is that because you have so many prefixes, you need to repeat the image URL for each one:

```
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%), url('../img/bg.png') !important;
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))), url('../img/bg.png') !important;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%), url('../img/bg.png') !important;
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%), url('../img/bg.png') !important;
background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%), url('../img/bg.png') !important;
```

I left the `!important` tokens in but you should probably remove them if they aren't there for any specific purpose. I did remove the `-ms-linear-gradient()` line though, because it's absolutely not needed.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably going to require two elements, but you can use a pseudo-element to make things a little cleaner. [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UNdJa/).

```
#yourelement {
    position: relative;

    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(0,0,0,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,1))) !important;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
    background: linear-gradient(to right,  rgba(0,0,0,1) 0%,rgba(0,0,0,0) 50%,rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%) !important;
}

#yourelement:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    background: url('../img/bg.png') !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried it and with luck this worked in my safari browser.

```
background: url('img.png'), -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,transparent 50%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
```

so in your case you would use

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1)), color-stop(50%,transparent), color-stop(100%,rgba(0, 0, 0, 1))), url('../img/bg.png');
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/je7Hr/1/)