# How to change body's background for a linear gradient using a fade in effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to get the body's background to change onload for a linear gradient onload event.

I have done this by far:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
  $("body").addClass("bc");
});
```

```css
    /*CSS*/
    .bc{
        transition: background 1s;
        background: red; /*This actually gets the fade in animation effect*/
        /*background: linear-gradient(30deg, red, yellow) This doesn't get the effect*/
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I also tried to use Keyframes to change the background for a linear gradient but it changes it sharply

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6542212 says gradients are not supported in transitions (although the spec says they should).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you cannot add transition on linear-gradient, you may use pseudo element that you make fading and you can easily adjust it's background and also the background of the body to create the needed effect:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('body').addClass('bc')
}, 500); /*Control the start of fading here */
```

```css
/*CSS*/

body {
  transition: background 5s;
  background:linear-gradient(60deg, yellow, red);
  height:100vh;
  margin:0;
}

body:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 3s; /* control the speed of fading here*/
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, red, pink)
}

body.bc:before {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you have an example with keyframes animation:

```js
$(document).ready(function (){
      $("body").addClass("bc");
});
```

```css
/*CSS*/
@-webkit-keyframes GradientAnimation {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-moz-keyframes GradientAnimation {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@-o-keyframes GradientAnimation {
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}
@keyframes GradientAnimation { 
    0%{background-position:0% 50%}
    50%{background-position:100% 50%}
    100%{background-position:0% 50%}
}

.bc{
  background-color: red;
  background: linear-gradient(270deg, #e4cc08, #e45708);
  background-size: 400% 400%;

  -webkit-animation: GradientAnimation 15s ease infinite;
  -moz-animation: GradientAnimation 15s ease infinite;
  -o-animation: GradientAnimation 15s ease infinite;
  animation: GradientAnimation 15s ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

And nice generator for this here: https://www.gradient-animator.com/

Answer (score 0):

CSS transition works, but it lays an overlay over background. If you have text, which is placed above background, it will be overlaid.

i wrote a solution with jQuery, where you can define colors and order in which they would be changed from one to another:

in the example below, the animation goes from green to purple, and then back to green, and so on, until the animation stops after defined number of seconds

```js
var stopAfterSec = 23;
var speed = 15;

var purple = [255, 26, 26];
var green = [26, 255, 118];
var sea_green = [26, 255, 244];

var order = [green, sea_green, purple];

var current = 0;
var direction = -1;
var color = end_color = order[current];

function updateGradient() {
  if (color[0] == end_color[0] && color[1] == end_color[1] && color[2] == end_color[2]) {
    direction = (current > 0 && current < order.length - 1) ? direction : (-1) * Math.sign(direction);
    current += direction;
    end_color = order[current];
  }

  $('.animGradientEfron').css({
    background: "-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(" + color[0] + ", " + color[1] + ", " + color[2] + ", 0.48) 100%)"
  });
  for (var i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    if (color[i] != end_color[i]) {
      color[i] += Math.sign((end_color[i] - color[i]));
    }
  }
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  var startGradientAnimation = setInterval(updateGradient, speed);

  setTimeout(function() {
    clearInterval(startGradientAnimation);
  }, stopAfterSec * 1000);

});
```

```css
.animGradientEfron {
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="animGradientEfron"></div>
```

Answer (score -2):

please refer it

```
 .css {
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat;
   background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)), color-stop(100%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65))), url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat;
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat;
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat;
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat;
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 59%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65) 100%), url('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg') no-repeat;
 height: 200px;

 }
 <div class="css"></div>
```

[Use css gradient over background image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image)

Comment: It does the same job but 2 seconds after, Linear gradient won't show the fade in effect,  and it's not very effective because you are using jquery before you know it's loaded. Im sorry man but this is not what I was looking for, thank you anyway. :)

Comment: If you believe the referenced post provides answer to the question you should use *a duplicate* [flag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: I thought this question is resolved by this link that why I just put a reference link here.