# CSS - When I used a gradient background I found the image disappeared

Tags: html, css, background-image, background-color

I know I'm pretty pathetic but I ve this problem:

I used an image and a colour for the background of a page in my homepage. Everything ok but the result...mmmmm. Then I found on internet some code for obtaining a wonderful gradient colour on the background colour. I think it ll improve the page in an amazing way

BUT

the image disappeared... If I take the "internet code" for the gradient colour the image come back.
Here s the code:

```
    #particles-js {
    width: 100%;
/*from here the image*/
background-image: url('../images/Image.png');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: center;
background-size: 40% ;
/*from here the code I found on internet*/
background: #e0f3fa;  
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #e0f3fa 0%, #d8f0fc 57%, #4dc8f0 100%, #b6dffd 100%);  
background: -image-webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover,  #e0f3fa 0%,#d8f0fc 57%,#4dc8f0 100%,#b6dffd 100%);  
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center,  #e0f3fa 0%,#d8f0fc 57%,#4dc8f0 100%,#b6dffd 100%); 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#e0f3fa', endColorstr='#b6dffd',GradientType=1 ); 
}
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please, show us your css, so we can help you better.

Comment: I think this answer is what you're looking for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image

Comment: Because a gradient background **is not a color**...it's treated as a background image and so overrides your previous rule.

Comment: That's because `background`property overrides previous `background-mage`.

Comment: `Background` is shortcut way of defining everything about background. This means you define `background-image` also if you use `background`. Also be aware that you cannot use linear gradient and background image together on same div