# CSS gradient on a background image

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add a gradient to a background image, so the gradient is coming from top and from the bottom, exactly like this - https://prnt.sc/qjqng6 
The background image code -

```
body {
  background-image: url('images/city.jpg');
  background-position: top;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

I've tried adding the gradient, but I've only succeeded to add a gradient from bottom to top only. 
I would appreciate if someone could help me with the code and explain how it works.

Comment: Try the accepted solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this:

```
//Adapt the colors
.body {
  background: linear-gradient(to top, #6C2D72, #A53A6F);
}
```

Comment: How do I turn the opacity of the gradient down? It's just solid.

Answer (score 0):

CSS:

```
.gradient-bg{
    display: inline-block;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%, rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.89) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(0,0,0,0.65)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,0,0,0)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.89) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.89) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.89) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(0,0,0,0) 0%,rgba(249, 249, 249, 0.89) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#a6000000', endColorstr='#00000000',GradientType=0 );

}
span{
  position: absolute;
  top: 183px;
}
img{
  position:relative;
  z-index:-1;
  display:block;
  height:200px; width:auto;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div class="gradient-bg">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/bDGCn.png">
  <span>Your Text Here</span>
</div>
```

Comment: That seems to add only a gradient from the bottom till the middle.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```css
body {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, rgba(241, 110, 110, 0.64), rgba(247, 102, 211, 0.35)),url(https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1578109520926-27e174c2b776?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=282&q=80);
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 900px;
}
```

```html
<body>
 
</body>
```