# CSS Book like shadows

Tags: css

I have a flipbook page and am looking to make it look like an actual book. E.g. this flipbook example I found online:

[image]

Anyone knows how can the shadows on the outside and the ones on the inside can be achieved?

Comment: Have you made an attempt yourself? I Imagine a couple of [gradient overlays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16589519/use-css-gradient-over-background-image) would do the trick (you could try using e.g. box-shadows, but gradients would give you more flexibility in the layout of the HTML)

Comment: I did but couldn't figure it out. Would not post the question if I didn't. 
Thanks for the suggestion @DBS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For outside shadow you can use:**  box-shadow:15px -2px 12px 13px #dedbdb;

**For inside shadow you can use:** box-shadow: inset 15px -2px 19px 0px #dedbdb;

**For both( the same time):**
box-shadow: inset 15px -2px 19px 0px #dedbdb, 15px -2px 12px 13px #dedbdb;

**Adjust the shadow according to your choice**