# Multiple Full Size Background Image

Tags: html, css

So I have learned the different methods of setting up a background image that will automatically fill the browser. Is there a method using only html and css to set a fullscreen background image and then have another fullscreen background image below so that when I initially launch the site you will see the first image and as you scroll down the second one will appear?

Comment: do you mine share some pieces of codes?

Comment: html {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/XHbch.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;}

Comment: All I really know what to do at this point is to set up the one background image. I was thinking of setting up two <div> and applying a background to each div. Would that approach work?

Comment: try `background: url('banner1.jpg'), url('banner2.jpg');
background-position: left top, left top;
background-repeat: no-repeat, repeat;`
Play with background-position until it does what you want.

IE < 9 does not support this feature. thanks to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11821285/css-two-background-images) question.

Answer (score 2):

You could do it like this:

**[Working Example](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/B9qD7/)**

```
html {
    height:1200px;
    width:600px
}
body {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(http://example.png) no-repeat 50% 600px/600px, url(http://example2.png) no-repeat top/600px 600px;
}
```

Or, if it needs to be fluid, like this:

**[Working Example 2](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/B9qD7/1/)**

```
body, html {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    margin:0;
}
#div1 {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(http://example.png) no-repeat 50%/cover;
}
#div2 {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    background: url(http://example2.png) no-repeat 50%/cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS3 allows this sort of thing and it looks like this:

```
body {
background-image: url(images/bgtop.png), url(images/bg.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x, repeat;
}
```

[The current versions of all the major browsers now support it](http://caniuse.com/#search=multiple%20backgrounds), however if you need to support IE8 or below, then the best way you can work around it is to have extra divs:

```
<body>
<div id="bgTopDiv">
    content here
</div>
</body>
body{
background-image: url(images/bg.png);
}
#bgTopDiv{
background-image: url(images/bgTop.png);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
}
```